# Statically Compiling Qt 4.6.2

Tags: qt, static, linker, compilation

This what I did but it results in errors:

1: In win32-msvc2008\qmake.conf I set `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -O1 -Og -GL -MD`

2: From MSVC2008 CMD I run `vcvarsall.bat x86` and `vcvars32.bat "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin`

3: From Qt 4.6.2 CMD I run the following

> C:\Qt\4.6.2>configure -release 
>   -nomake examples -nomake demos -no-exceptions -n o-stl -no-rtti -no-qt3support -no-scripttools -no-openssl -no-opengl -no-webkit
>   -no-phonon -no-style-motif -no-style-cde -no-style-cleanlooks -no-style-plastique
>   -no-sql-sqlite -platform win32-msvc2008 -static -qt-libjpeg
>   -qt-zlib -qt-libpng

and then `nmake`

However, I ended up every time with these errors:

> ```
>     link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.6.2\lib"
> ```
>
> /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.6.2\lib" /NOLOGO
>   /INCR EMENTAL:NO /MANIFEST
>   /MANIFESTFILE:"tmp\obj\release_static\assistant_adp.interme
>   diate.manifest" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
>   "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32'
>   name='Micro
>   soft.Windows.Common-Controls'
>   version='6.0.0.0'
>   publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df '
>   language='*'
>   processorArchitecture='*'"
>   /OUT:......\bin\assistant_adp.exe @C
>   :\DOCUME~1\Geeko\LOCALS~1\Temp\nm3F8.tmp
>   fontpanel.obj : MSIL .netmodule or
>   module compiled with /GL found;
>   restarting li nk with /LTCG; add /LTCG
>   to the link command line to improve
>   linker performance main.obj : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "class QObject * __cdecl qt
>   _plugin_instance_qjpeg(void)" (?qt_plugin_instance_qjpeg@@YAPAVQObject@@XZ)
>   ......\bin\assistant_adp.exe : fatal
>   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077:
>   '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\VC\BIN \link.EXE"' : return
>   code '0x460' Stop.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN \nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2' Stop.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2' Stop.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2' Stop.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2' Stop.

Thank you in deed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do it with MS VS 2008 and it worked.

```sh
C:\Qt\4.6.2>configure -release -static -opensource -no-fast -no-exceptions -no-accessibility -no-rtti -no-stl -no-opengl -no-openvg -no-incredibuild-xge -no-style-plastique -no-style-cleanlooks -no-style-motif -no-style-cde -no-style-windowsce -no-style-windowsmobile -no-style-s60 -no-gif -no-libpng -no-libtiff -no-libjpeg -no-libmng -no-qt3support -no-mmx -no-3dnow -no-sse -no-sse2 -no-iwmmxt -no-openssl -no-dbus -platform win32-msvc2008 -arch windows -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-multimedia -no-audio-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -webkit -no-declarative
```

However, I get these errors when building a project that links statically to QWebKit:

```
1>Creating library C:\Users\Geeko\Desktop\Qt\TestQ\Release\TestQ.lib and object C:\Users\Geeko\Desktop\Qt\TestQ\Release\TestQ.exp

1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginPackageWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _VerQueryValueW@16 referenced in function "class WebCore::String __cdecl WebCore::getVersionInfo(void * const,class WebCore::String const &)" (?getVersionInfo@WebCore@@YA?AVString@1@QAXABV21@@Z)

1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginPackageWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoW@16 referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall WebCore::PluginPackage::fetchInfo(void)" (?fetchInfo@PluginPackage@WebCore@@AAE_NXZ)

1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginPackageWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetFileVersionInfoSizeW@8 referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall WebCore::PluginPackage::fetchInfo(void)" (?fetchInfo@PluginPackage@WebCore@@AAE_NXZ)

1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginDatabaseWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathRemoveFileSpecW@4 referenced in function "class WebCore::String __cdecl WebCore::safariPluginsDirectory(void)" (?safariPluginsDirectory@WebCore@@YA?AVString@1@XZ)

1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginDatabaseWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SHGetValueW@24 referenced in function "void __cdecl WebCore::addWindowsMediaPlayerPluginDirectory(class WTF::Vector<class WebCore::String,0> &)" (?addWindowsMediaPlayerPluginDirectory@WebCore@@YAXAAV?$Vector@VString@WebCore@@$0A@@WTF@@@Z)

1>QtWebKit.lib(PluginDatabaseWin.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathCombineW@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl WebCore::addMacromediaPluginDirectories(class WTF::Vector<class WebCore::String,0> &)" (?addMacromediaPluginDirectories@WebCore@@YAXAAV?$Vector@VString@WebCore@@$0A@@WTF@@@Z)

1>C:\Users\Geeko\Desktop\Qt\TestQ\Release\TestQ.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

Do I need to check something in the Qt project options ?
I have QtCore, QtGui, Network and WebKit checked.

Comment: Webkit can't be built with static flag!

Comment: Actually I did successfully statically compiled it

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these environment variables :

- `QTDIR` : c:\Qt\4.6.2 or wherever you unzipped the Qt sources.
- `QMAKESPEC` : win32-msvc2008
- `%QTDIR%/bin` to the `PATH`

And use the 'Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt' (in the Tools menu in VS2008) instead of the Qt one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
This is what I've got. It seems there is some progress though :)
Any thoughts ?
BTE I followed this: http://www.formortals.com/build-qt-static-

c1xx : fatal error C1027: Inconsistent values for /Ym between creation and use of precompiled header
qsequentialanimationgroup.cpp
c1xx : fatal error C1027: Inconsistent values for /Ym between creation and use of precompiled header
qparallelanimationgroup.cpp
c1xx : fatal error C1027: Inconsistent values for /Ym between creation and use of precompiled header
qpauseanimation.cpp

Comment: The inconsistencies may be caused by object left from a previous compilation. Did you clean up the Qt directory? -- BTW your link leads to a 404 error...

Comment: Hi again, I tried nmake clean then nmake this time but still:
c1xx : fatal error C1027: Inconsistent values for /Ym between creation and use of precompiled header
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
the website is http://www.formortals.com/build-qt-static-small-microsoft-intel-gcc-compiler/

Comment: Maybe the `nmake clean` isn't just enough, and you need to run `nmake confclean` too -- this will cleanup your makefiles -- then restart from the `configure` step.

Comment: gregseth:
Still with this error:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class QObject * __cdecl qt
_plugin_instance_qjpeg(void)" (?qt_plugin_instance_qjpeg@@YAPAVQObject@@XZ)
..\..\..\bin\assistant_adp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN
\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN
\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Comment: shall I use vs solution/project files to do it from vs 2008 ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the std::string types Qt is choosing per defaults?

It's a little compiler switch **-Zc:wchar_t-** that explicitly defines wchar_t as an unsigned short instead of a built in type. 
If you omit the *-* at the end, i.e. **-Zc:wchar_t** it changes and might be more compatible to your project.